# What simple sentence types am I missing?

Tags: traducción

I created a table with various simple sentences in English translated into Spanish by Translate.com/Google Translate and Bing.

It may be interesting to note that they usually render the translations differently.

Am I missing any basic "taco" sentences? I will add them if I am. It can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/LU7qm/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly add the Pretérito Anterior, even though it is rarely used nowadays, at least in spoken language.

Why do you like tacos so much?

Comment: What's not to like about tacos? I work near one of the best taquerias in existance (Los Grullenses), my wife makes superior tacos, Chipotle's Crispy Veggie Tacos are "to dye for" and then there's the best taco truck around that parks just a couple of blocks from here - I'm going to try out their Vampiras Tacos Friday. IOW: I am to Tacos what Wimpy was to hamburgers, what Garfield is to lasagna, and what Dagwood was to big sandwiches.

Answer (score 4):

I checked your table, and what I can find is BOTH, Google and Bing are giving you unnatural (and some times wrong) translations most of the time. However Google's translations seem to be much more accurate than Bing's ones. I speak spanish from Mexico.

Comment: Thanks; I expected as much. Duolingo sometimes has awkward English translations, too. Also, oftentimes what is considered correct by translate.com is unacceptable by Duolingo. Which goes to show you: there are multiple ways to flay (or filet) a feline, AND machine translation still has a long way to go. Personally, I think good machine translation is impossible. Finally: I am actually a cat lover, so don't take the previous expression too seriously.